# Framed in Vertical Mode

Tags: context

How can I create a ConTeXt framed environment such that `\ifvmode` is true?

```
\startframed[...]
    \ifvmode
        Vertical mode!
    \else
        Horizontal mode!
    \fi
\stopframed
```

*edit*

I was under the impression that [if an alignment was specified \framed would produce a \vbox](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupframed#Description). However it seems more of a faux-vbox since `ifvmode` is false and `nointerlineskip` is not allowed. Is there a combination of settings that guarantees vertical mode or before/after clauses which allow `\vbox\bgroup...\egroup` around the content?

Comment: Dependent on your `\framed` seetings you get a vertical box but when TeX make the mode check you're already in hirizontal mode because ConTeXt add a `\strut` at the begin and end of the frame. To ensure _no_ `\strut` is added at the begin you the frame you have to add `strut=none` to the `\framed` settings.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I'm in horizontal mode even with `strut=no` (or none).

Comment: Since you don't provide a working minimal example I can't tell what you're doing wrong but I get vertical mode when I use `strut=none` in combination with a `align` setting and a value for either `width` or `height`.

Comment: It must be `strut=none` rather than `strut=no` (when I tested the former I forgot to remove some other macros).

Comment: This should be an answer because the ConTeXtGarden wiki pages [Framed](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Framed) and [setupframed](https://www.contextgarden.net/Command/setupframed) both list `strut=no` as valid syntax and as examples. Maybe also show how strut affects font size modifications within the `\framed`, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536361/framed-and-interline-space#comment1355019_536361).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\framed` command creates a `horizontal` box by default but when you apply a `width` or `height` setting in combination with a `align` setting you switch to a `vertical` box.

The tricky part is how to check for vertical mode because setting a `width` and `align` setting isn't enough. The problem is that ConTeXt adds a `\strut` at the begin and end of the content and the `\strut` at the begin switches to `horizontal` mode. The example with the `\vbox` demonstrates what happens here.

```
\startbuffer[modetest]
    \ifvmode
        Vertical mode!
    \else
        Horizontal mode!
    \fi
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\startframed[width=max,align=normal]
    \getbuffer[modetest]
\stopframed

\ruledvbox\bgroup
    \strut\getbuffer[modetest]\removeunwantedspaces\strut
\egroup

\stoptext
```

[image]

The obvious solution after we know `\strut` is the culprit is to disable it with the `strut=no` option. Unlike the expections we still get `horizontal` mode because ConTeXt adds `\noindent` at the begin of the content which moves us out of `vertical` mode.

```
\startbuffer[modetest]
    \ifvmode
        Vertical mode!
    \else
        Horizontal mode!
    \fi
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\startframed[width=max,align=normal,strut=no]
    \getbuffer[modetest]
\stopframed

\ruledvbox\bgroup
    \noindent\getbuffer[modetest]\removeunwantedspaces
\egroup

\stoptext
```

[image]

To finally solve our problem we have to use the special `strut=none` option which is a `\framed` only option. Unlike the previous `no` key the `none` option doesn't insert anything at the begin or end of the content which keeps us in `vertical` mode when we perform the check and ConTeXt finally shows **Vertical mode!**.

```
\startbuffer[modetest]
    \ifvmode
        Vertical mode!
    \else
        Horizontal mode!
    \fi
\stopbuffer

\starttext

\startframed[width=max,align=normal,strut=none]
    \getbuffer[modetest]
\stopframed

\ruledvbox\bgroup
    \getbuffer[modetest]
\egroup

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `background` does quite the same as `framed` and gives `true` to `\ifvmode`. A minimal example:

```
\definebackground
[nicenote]
[
framecolor=black,
background=color,
backgroundcolor=yellow,
frame=on, 
rulethickness=2pt,
offset=overlay,
leftoffset=1em,
rightoffset=1em,
width=\textwidth,
setups=framedsetups,
before=\blank,
after=\blank,
]
\starttext
\startnicenote 
\ifvmode
Vertical mode!
\else
Horizontal mode!
\fi
\stopnicenote 
\stoptext
```

[image]